# RGB Composite of Landsat-8 image

Tags: python, rgb, satellite, landsat

I am trying to create a RGB composite from individual bands of a Landsat-8 image. Tried options like np.dstack, also the below format

```
img[:,:,0] = b4
img[:,:,1] = b3
img[:,:,2] = b2
```

But keep getting an error

[Error Creating RGB band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izYHy.png)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue. In short, you need to normalize the arrays from 0-1 (and you may need to change your data type). I decided to write a post describing how to create and RGB composite from a Landsat-8 image.

Check it out here: https://colekrehbiel.wordpress.com/2017/10/01/creating-natural-color-rgb-composites-from-landsat-8-data-in-python/.

Comment: Try expanding your answer a little here too as the link may break in future